# Iterate through Vec<&str> and accumulate value to a variable when condition is fullfilled

Tags: loops, rust, vector, hashmap

My current attempt:

```
let fruits:Vec<&str> = vec!["Banana", "Peach"];
let fruits_hashmap: HashMap<_, _> = HashMap::from_iter([("Apple", 2),("Banana", 4),("Peach", 8)]);
let mut n = 0;
let c =  fruits.iter().map(|s| 
    
    match fruits_hashmap.get(s) {
        Some(value) => n |= value,
        None => println!("{} does not exist", s)
    });
return n;
```

But I get `warning: unused variable: fruits_hashmap` and also n is equal to 0 but it should be equal to 12.

Comment: `map` is lazy and does not activately iterate through. Use a `for..in` loop instead, or use `fold` / `reduce` instead.

Comment: `fold` would likely be a good choice, probably preceded by a `filter_map` to get the value out of the hashmap.

Comment: @Masklinn would you mind sharing a code snippet as an answer? It looks interesting!

Comment: Something along the lines of `let n = fruits.iter().filter_map(|f| fruits_hashmap.get(f)).fold(0, |a, b| a | b)` should work. Not tested so there may be a few type errors but it should be pretty close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you added `let c =`  because you had another warning before:

```
warning: unused `Map` that must be used
  --> src/lib.rs:8:5
   |
8  | /     fruits.iter().map(|s| match fruits_hashmap.get(s) {
9  | |         Some(value) => n |= value,
10 | |         None => println!("{} does not exist", s),
11 | |     });
   | |______^
   |
   = note: iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed
   = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
help: use `let _ = ...` to ignore the resulting value
   |
8  |     let _ = fruits.iter().map(|s| match fruits_hashmap.get(s) {
   |     +++++++
```

However, this isn't the solution. As the warning says, `iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed`. What you need is not `map()`, but a `for` loop:

```rust
for s in &fruits {
    match fruits_hashmap.get(s) {
        Some(value) => n |= value,
        None => println!("{} does not exist", s),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! Any difference between `for s in &fruits {` and `fruits.iter().for_each(|s| {` ?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL No observable effect, but the `for` loop is considered is more idiomatic, and also [recommended by the documentation of `for_each()` itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each). `for_each()` may be faster in some cases, but not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`map` creates a new iterator, but doesn't actually iterate it: that's why `fruits_hashmap` is unused. You *could* take this iterator and iterate it with a `for` loop or collect it, however, it's best to avoid side-effects in `map`. Instead, you can use `for_each`:

```
fruits.iter().for_each(|s| {
    match fruits_hashmap.get(s) {
        Some(value) => n |= value,
        None => println!("{} does not exist", s)
    }
});
```