# Search in Hashmap for a key potentially missing a char or having an extra char at the end

Tags: regex, rust, hashmap

Looking for a way to look for a word where the user is not smart enough to spell it correctly, I have already handled many cases (like capitalizing the word so it match the string expected on the backend), and then I wasted 30mn before realizing the user had yet another typo, missing an 's' (like using "Bananas" whereas the backend expect "Banana").

I am looking for a solution to handle this case, as well as the reverse one (singular on client side but plural expected, only considering with extra 's' or missing 's').

specifically the code is the following:

```
  for s in &fruits{
                        match m.get(&capitalize(s) as &str) {
                            Some(value) => n |= value,
                            None => println!("{} does not exist", s),
                        }
                    }
```

where m is a [hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061593/iterate-through-vecstr-and-accumulate-value-to-a-variable-when-condition-is-f)

The tricky part is I want to try to match twice, I was thinking about handle the none case with looking with an extra "s", and if not working again by removing last character, but it seems really verbose compared to what it could be.

Comment: To do this properly you'll need natural language processing, since there are a number of ways to form the plural of a word. Some words add "s", some add "es", and some have nonstandard forms like man->men.

Comment: excellent point but I just want to handle simple typo mistakes, I'm already doing a lot for the user (who is an IT Admin), so I don't think it is justified to go that far.

Comment: The regexp `bananas?` will match `banana` or `bananas`

Comment: but hashmap cannot use regex, can they?

Comment: I don't use Rust, but I suspect not. But you tagged the question `regex` so I thought that's what you were looking for.

Comment: What you should do is canonicalize all words when creating the hash map, and similarly canonicalize the user's input before matching it.

Comment: There's no "close enough" hashmap implementation in Rust, or any other language I can think of off the top, but you could make an implementation that *feels* like a hash without behaving strictly like one, like an [`impl Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) that handles *close enough* matches by doing a loose search, regex or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is the [`fst` crate](https://docs.rs/fst/latest/fst/). It's a library that very efficiently stores sets and maps where the keys are strings, and allows for "almost match" searches. For instance, one of the examples in the documentation shows you how to search for all strings that have a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of at most one of your query (which is very close to what you are asking):

```rust
// A convenient way to create sets in memory.
let keys = vec!["fa", "fo", "fob", "focus", "foo", "food", "foul"];
let set = Set::from_iter(keys)?;

// Build our fuzzy query.
let lev = Levenshtein::new("foo", 1)?;

// Apply our fuzzy query to the set we built.
let mut stream = set.search(lev).into_stream();

let keys = stream.into_strs()?;
assert_eq!(keys, vec!["fo", "fob", "foo", "food"]);
```

Different kind of queries are supported, for instance you can enable case-insensitivity.

Maps are also supported, but currently the value type is very restricted (only integers I think), but you can just store an external array with the actual values, and store in an `fst` map the indices to these maps. `fst` maps also cannot be modified. A simple implementation of this idea would be:

```rust
use fst::{Map, levenshtein::{Levenshtein, LevenshteinError}};

struct GoodMap<V> {
    values: Vec<V>,
    map: Map<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl<V> GoodMap<V> {
    fn new(mut data: Vec<(&str, V)>) -> fst::Result<Self> {
        data.sort_unstable(); // Strings need to be in lexicographical order
        let map = Map::from_iter(
            data
            .iter()
            .map(|(key, _)| *key)
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(i, key)| (key, i as u64))
        )?;
        let values = data.into_iter().map(|(_, value)| value).collect();
        Self { map, values }
    }

    fn get(&self, key: &str, allowed_typos: u32) -> Result<Vec<&T>, LevenshteinError> {
        let lev = Levenshtein::new(key, allowed_typos)?;
        Ok(self
            .map
            .search(&lev)
            .into_stream()
            .into_values()
            .into_iter()
            .map(|i| &self.values[i as usize])
            .collect()
        )
    }
}
```

Note that this code is, in itself, pretty inefficient for a variety of reasons, but it should get you started. Be sure to read the documentation of the `fst` crate: while it can be very efficient is well used, there are also quite a lot of pitfalls that can make your code very inefficient (such as creating `Levenshtein` automata with large `allowed_typos`).

These limitations allow `fst` being extremely fast, and manipulating huge amount of data, even if it doesn't fit in your RAM for instance. It also allows you searching multiple sets at once, or taking the intersection of sets in a query (and even more!).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was slooking for! Would you mind showing the full example with the hashmap? Because here all I can see is a vector of key values.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL I updated the question with an example. However, I encourage you to go read the documentation, as it's easy to write inefficient code with the `fst` crate, despite the amazing performance you can get with it if used properly. Also, it's a data structure that comes with a number of trade offs.

Comment: Also, note that this is *not* a hashmap (despite what you have asked in your question). Hashmaps are really not suited for "approximative" queries.